# WebDriver wait command is failing for Safari on Mac OS

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, safari, safaridriver

I have script to login to a site and then waiting for home button to get loaded. I have put fluentwait to wait for element to be visible. But WebDriver is not waiting and failing immediately as the home button is not loaded.

I have tried with fluentwait and webdriverwait but none of them are working.

Here is code I am trying.

```
By usernameInput = By.name("User”);
By passwordInput = By.name("Password”);
By loginButton = By.xpath("//input[@value='Sign In']”);
String URL = “https://demotest.mytest.com/"

WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get(URL);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
setText(usernameInput,”User1");
setText(passwordInput,”User1");
clickOnElement(loginButton);
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
```

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@title='Home']")));

Throws below error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:     '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'cnparmar-mac', ip: '10.168.104.60', os.name:     'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version:     '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: Safari,         browserVersion: 12.1.1, javascriptEnabled: true, platform: MAC,         platformName: MAC, safari:automaticInspection: false,     safari:automaticProfiling: false, safari:diagnose: false,     setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, webkit:WebRTC:     {DisableICECandidateFiltering: false, DisableInsecureMediaCapture:     false}}
Session ID: 1257BF8B-335E-4E80-8B08-CB15A77AD648
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[@title='Home']}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native     Method)
at         sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructo    rAccessorImpl.java:62)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingCo    nstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(    W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpRes    ponseCodec.java:122)
at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpRes    ponseCodec.java:49)
at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExec    utor.java:158)
at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(Drive    rCommandExecutor.java:83)
at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.jav    a:552)
at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver    .java:323)
at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWe    bDriver.java:428)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver    .java:315)
at     org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedCond    itions.java:205)
at     org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedCond    itions.java:201)
at     org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
at sample.Sample.loginAs(Sample.java:64)
at sample.Sample.test1(Sample.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.j    ava:62)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccess    orImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at         org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocati    onHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at     org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorke    r.java:125)
at     org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at     org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Ideally it should wait for Home button to get visible. but it is failing. This works on Chrome,Firefox, IE, Edge on Windows but only failing on Safari on MAC.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing up WebDriverWait and FluentWait classes.

Try using the following instead:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@title='Home']")));
```

Comment: I tried above code and it is not working. WebDriver throws same error.

Comment: Here are the imports.

    import java.util.function.Function;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

Comment: Hmm looks like you are probably suffering from this:  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106693. Does it work if you switch to ChromeDriver?

Comment: Any solution on this one?